# Send text from one vim buffer to another?

Tags: vim, viml

**Setting:** Vim session with multiple tabs, windows, and buffers.

**Goal:** Make Ex command that sends selected text from active buffer to another buffer in the session (preferably with autocompletion). By this I mean the text is *appended* to the *end of the target buffer*.

**Example:** Suppose you're in a buffer named `apple` and there is another buffer named `banana` in a different tab. You highlight the text you want to send to `banana` (say, a line that has text "asdf", and then type `:'<,'>append ban<TAB>` and vim autocompletes the text to `:append banana`. After pressing return, vim cuts the string "asdf" from `apple` and appends it to the end of `banana`.

The closest I've come is `:'<,'>!cat >> banana`; however, this only works if banana is in the same working directory as apple, and it fails to autocomplete with existing buffer names.

Is there a way to construct a vim script/viml function that does this?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
function! Append(l1, l2, buffer)
  let currentBuffer = @%
  let currentRegister = @z
  execute a:l1 . "," . a:l2 . 'y z'
  execute "buffer " . a:buffer
  normal G"zp<C-O>
  let @z = currentRegister
  execute "buffer " . currentBuffer
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 -complete=buffer -range Append call Append(<line1>, <line2>, <f-args>)
```

We remember the current buffer and the current value of the `z` register, as we'll use that for yanking; we yank, then switch buffers, go to bottom and paste; then put everything back the way it was. `-nargs=1 -complete=buffer` gives you autocomplete for buffer names.